# What is the best documentation script for a project?

Tags: php, open-source, documentation, project

I coded a codeigniter library called [Aauth](http://github.com/emreakay/Codeigniter-Aauth) and i want to create documentation for it.

My need is a documentation script written in php.

Comment: I would comment/document my code on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php documentor is really good

http://pear.php.net/package/phpDocumentor/redirected

Answer (score 2):

We use PHPDoc: http://www.phpdoc.org/ for our PHP documentation